# What is the equivalent of this setup network in netplan .yaml configuration?

Tags: networking, netplan, openstack

I'm following this guide to bring up a openstack environment [openstack network guide](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/environment-networking-controller.html)

When it's time to setup the network interfaces the guide recommend to use the first one as the management (and I got it), and the second one as the provider network.

The provider should not have IP address:

```
auto INTERFACE_NAME
iface INTERFACE_NAME inet manual
up ip link set dev $IFACE up
down ip link set dev $IFACE down
```

Now, my question is: what is the equivalent commands I should declare in the .yaml config file?

P.S. I am using ubuntu 22.04 with renderer: NetworkManager

Comment: I don't immediately know the correct replacement for this in context, but https://bugs.launchpad.net/openstack-manuals/+bug/2025516 has been opened to track the fact that the documentation is out-of-date with respect to Ubuntu.

Comment: BTW, why are you using the NetworkManager renderer in an openstack environment?  The default for Ubuntu Server is networkd.